# Group similar items in a master list and create new lists based on grouped items

Tags: python, list

I am trying to create several new lists from one master list whereby the new lists contain similar items from the master list. Specifically, I have a list of bus routes. Here is a sample data set:

```
[u'Bus04_00_00_IB_pts_Line', u'Bus04_00_00_OB_pts_Line', u'Bus15_00_00_IB_pts_Line', u'Bus15_00_00_OB_pts_Line']
```

Most bus routes have an inbound (IB) and an outbound (OB) item, (and some have multiple IBs and OBs, and some have only one route, b/c they are loop routes). Eventually, I want to merge the IB and OB routes in mapping software (which I already know how to do)...

I originally created the filenames so that the first 5 characters represent the bus route, whether or not it's IB or OB. Therefore, I am able to group similar items based on the first 5 characters. For example, when I write:

```
for route in routes:
    print route[0:5]
```

I get:

```
>>> 
Bus04
Bus04
Bus15
Bus15
```

How can I "group" the files that pertain to `Bus04` and `Bus04`, and `Bus15` and `Bus15` into new lists, such that I get:

`[u'Bus04_00_00_IB_pts_Line', u'Bus04_00_00_OB_pts_Line']` and `[u'Bus15_00_00_IB_pts_Line', u'Bus15_00_00_OB_pts_Line']` as separate lists?

I am thinking something along the lines of looping through each item, looking at the first five characters of each, then either create a new list with each new five character item that comes up (and add that item to the new list) or checking whether a list already exists and appending the similar item to it.

I'm having a hard time writing this out in code, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for this:

```
import collections

L = [u'Bus04_00_00_IB_pts_Line', u'Bus04_00_00_OB_pts_Line', u'Bus15_00_00_IB_pts_Line', u'Bus15_00_00_OB_pts_Line']
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
for elem in L:
    d[elem.split('_')[0]].append(elem)
print(dict(d))
```

This produces:

```
{u'Bus04': [u'Bus04_00_00_IB_pts_Line', u'Bus04_00_00_OB_pts_Line'],
 u'Bus15': [u'Bus15_00_00_IB_pts_Line', u'Bus15_00_00_OB_pts_Line']}
```

Unlike some of the other solutions proposed thus far, this works irrespective of the order in which entries appear in the input list.

Comment: But it imposes that the elements are hashable (which they are in this case), so that's OK, but I think it's worth mentioning.  One other suggestion is, rather than doing `dict(d)` at the end, you could do:  `d.default_factory = None` to make the defaultdict behave like a regular dictionary for almost all practical purposes.

Comment: @mgilson: I think the `dict` call was solely to make it look better when printed (i.e. no `defaultdict(<type 'list'>, etc..`).

Comment: @DSM -- That's what I figured as well.  but I was super excited when I learned about the `default_factory` attribute, so I've made it a note to proclaim it's goodness from now on :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) with a custom key function such as `lambda x: x[0:5]`.

Here's a demo that gives you a static list (i.e. not just generators):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> lst = [u'Bus04_00_00_IB_pts_Line', u'Bus04_00_00_OB_pts_Line', u'Bus15_00_00_IB_pts_Line', u'Bus15_00_00_OB_pts_Line']
>>> [(key, list(val)) for key, val in itertools.groupby(lst, lambda x: x[0:5])]
Out[9]:
[(u'Bus04', [u'Bus04_00_00_IB_pts_Line', u'Bus04_00_00_OB_pts_Line']),
 (u'Bus15', [u'Bus15_00_00_IB_pts_Line', u'Bus15_00_00_OB_pts_Line'])]
```

Comment: don't forget to sort the list before using `groupby`

Answer (score 2):

```
import collections

lists = collections.defaultdict(list)
for item in masterlist:
    lists[item[:5]].append(item)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use groupby with a lambda keyfunction for this.

```
from itertools import groupby
results = groupby(data, key=lambda x: x[0:5])

>>> for item, values in results:
>>>     print item, list(values)
Bus04 [u'Bus04_00_00_IB_pts_Line', u'Bus04_00_00_OB_pts_Line']
Bus15 [u'Bus15_00_00_IB_pts_Line', u'Bus15_00_00_OB_pts_Line']
```

As mentioned by NPE in his solution, the original list must be a sorted list.

However, if you only need to deal with one entry at a time, this solution is very memory efficient, as the generator only yields one value and then waits until the next value is ready to be used.